# PHP+Memcached exceptions when running via CLI

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, memcached, libmemcached

We recently started using the Memcached cache adapter provided by ZF2.  While the server appears to be running perfectly when using the web browser (Apache HTTP Server), I have seen two different exceptions when running the application from the CLI.  The exception appears to occur when `Zend\Session\SaveHandler\Cache` writes the session to memory.

The first exception returned an error code of 47 (`MEMCACHED_SERVER_TEMPORARILY_DISABLED`).  After exhausting many options, I decided to try recompiling Memcached, libmemcached, and the PECL extension.  After doing this, I started getting a different result code—26 (`MEMCACHED_ERRNO`).  The result message for this code reads "SYSTEM ERROR: Broken pipe."

In the cache adapter, the `internalSetItem($normalizedKey, $value)` method checks the boolean value returned by `Memcached::set($key, $value, $expiration)`.  If it is false, a failure has occurred, and the ZF2 adapter will throw an exception based on the `Memcached::getResultCode()` and `Memcached::getResultMessage()` methods.  Prior to this, we simply weren't checking for result codes or messages, so it is possible that it has been happening all along.

My development environment specifications are as follows:

- PHP 5.5 with Memcached 2.2.0 (PECL)
- Memcached 1.4.20
- Libmemcached 1.0.18
- Zend Framework 2

**EDIT:**  I have narrowed the problem down to a single action in a single controller, but I am still at a loss as to why this is happening.  We have a ZF2 controller action that basically loops through a bunch of cron jobs and forks them off in their own processes.  It goes like this...

1. Loop through cron jobs
2. Run `pcntl_fork()` to create new process
3. Run `exec('/usr/bin/php index.php JOB_NAME')`

As it turns out, the third step executes without any problems.  Each job is running exactly as expected, but it seems like the forking is creating a problem with Memcached in the parent process.  That's where I am now.

Comment: If link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714127/memcacheset-broken-pipe have some help for you ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, while I did come across that question/answer, it does not apply to my situation.

Comment: If you are using memcached as a session store, I'd suggest running session_write_close() before the fork operation.